# Set null dates on Google Chart Timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Im trying to create a Timeline chart using Google Chart API. However the problem is I can't handle null dates on specific rows.

How do you hide rows that have null Start or End dates?

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', errorHandler); 
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

    dataTable.addRows([         
        [ 
            'NTC', 
            'NTC', 
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Briefing Meeting',
            'Baseline',
            new Date('07/07/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Concept Design', 
            'Baseline',     
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Concept Design', 
            'Forecast',     
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Concept Design', 
            'Actual',     
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Detail Design', 
            'Baseline', 
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Detail Design', 
            'Forecast', 
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date('07/06/2016'),   
        ],
        [ 
            'Detail Design', 
            'Actual', 
            new Date('07/05/2016'),
            new Date(),   
        ],
    ]);

    var colors = [];
    var colorMap = {
        Baseline: '#425cfb',
        Forecast: '#f8ac08',
        Actual: '#06af90',
        NTC: '#1b9e2e'
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 1)]);
    }  

    var options = {
        colors: colors,
        timeline: {
            showBarLabels: false, 
            groupByRowLabel: true,

            // rowLabelStyle: {fontName: 'Helvetica', fontSize: 24, color: '#603913'},
            barLabelStyle: { fontName: 'Garamond', fontSize: 6 },
        },

        interpolateNulls: true,
    };
}
```

It displays invalid datetime if I set new Date(0), Is there a workaround here?

Comment: Dubzcan you create a fiddle?

Comment: This is the fiddle I have created. This is the revised one on what I have posted here.
https://jsfiddle.net/6s65tat2/

As you can see, there shouldn't be a date displaying on the other rows eg., forecast and actual since it is set to new Date(), but it return the current date which is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/txr3k2z0/

Comment: How do you generate the dates? Maybe an approach would be changing the serverside code instead of the javascript.

Comment: The dates is from the database, which is fetch using PHP, the values is then pass on the javascript which is declare as new Date(). Well the problem is how to display a row when dates is not available?

Comment: share the relevant PHP or SQL statement, should be easy to filter out there...

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the already incorrect rows when you have the possibility to filter these posts at your server code is a waste of time and resources. **Try to filter these in your PHP instead!**

Google provides you with a [filter method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods) which you can use to filter your rows. I've also used the [DataView class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) in this solution.

First I created a `filterDate` at the same time as the rest of our empty `new Date()`s, then I 'zeroed' the milliseconds, as there might pass a millisecond or two before this is executed.

```
//use this one to determine what date to filter away.
var filterDate = new Date();
filterDate.setMilliseconds(0);
//Convert to JSON
filterDate = filterDate.toJSON();
```

Then I filter the rows I wish to use, using the filter option `test` which executes a function, passing the value, row, column and datatable as parameters. Should return `false` if you wish to exclude the row:

```
//filter the rows we actually want
var someRows = dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 2,
  test: testFunc
}, {
  column: 3,
  test: testFunc
}]);
```

In our function that we call, `testFunc` we 'zero' the milliseconds, and convert it to JSON and then compare to our `filterDate`. If it's the same, we judge that the row should be excluded:

```
//This is our test function
function testFunc(value) {
  value.setMilliseconds(0);
  return value.toJSON() !== filterDate;
}
```

Lastly we initiate a `DataView` from our `dataTable` and we set our rows to be the ones we just filtered:

```
//Create a dataView object from our dataTable, and set the rows to the ones we just filtered
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
dataView.setRows(someRows);
```

And we're good to go, but as already stated, you should try to filter these at your serverside instead.

[JSFiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/txr3k2z0/4/)